# Cannot do $STH->execute() with PDO

Tags: php, insert, pdo

I'm [finally] learning PDO, and I've been dealing for the past hour with a problem that I cannot seem to solve. I have this code:

```
//Simple script that connects to mysql and database.
$db = new PDO ("mysql:host=".Configuration::get('MysqlServername').";dbname=".Configuration::get('MysqlDatabase').";charset=UTF-8",
          Configuration::get('MysqlUsername'),
          Configuration::get('MysqlPassword')) or die ("Error connecting");

// To test why it doesn't work
$STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO htranslations (keyword, en, page, last) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())") or die ("Error preparing");
$STH->bindValue(1, "New_test", PDO::PARAM_STR) or die ("Error binding 1");
$STH->bindValue(2, "New test", PDO::PARAM_STR) or die ("Error binding 2");
$STH->bindValue(3, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PDO::PARAM_STR) or die ("Error binding 3");
$STH->execute() or die ("Error executing");
```

**Note**: The `or die` are set only as a temporary measure to test where the error is originated. This code is simply not working, and I cannot figure out why. Now, what I've tried:

- When doing `var_dump($db);`, I get `object(PDO)#1 (0) { }` on my browser. I guess this is NOT what it's supposed to be, but I have no idea and couldn't find much online. The `or die` statement not being executed makes me think that this might be right.
- The error displayed is `Error executing`. This means that the last query couldn't be executed, but that doesn't help much since it could be a problem originated previously.
- The Configuration class is returning the right values. It was working previously with mysql and I tested it to see if it returned the right values (it does).
- I'm in 000webhost.com free account. From [this forum post](http://www.free-installations.info/threads/000webhost-com-pdo-and-php-5-3.3053/) and [this other](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/27114-possible-use-pdo-000webhost.html) there shouldn't be any problem with the PDO here. Furthermore, `print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());` returns mysql, sqlite and sqlite2.
- The other way around, inserting the values in an array in the execute() statement, doesn't work either.

The working previous mysql_* code was (it was escaped previously):

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO htranslations (keyword, en, page, last) VALUES ('$Id', '$Text', '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."', now())";
 mysql_query($sql);
```

**Can you see what I'm doing wrong? If not, can you at least point me in some direction to keep testing it?** I followed mainly (but not only) [this tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you get from `var_dump($STH->ErrorInfo())`? You'll need to run it after the execute, so you'll need to remove that `die()` call for the time being.

Comment: Thanks to this I solved it. Apparently the previous mysql code was not working properly but didn't test it enough (only once). Simply needed to add "auto_increment" to the id value and everything worked.
It returned duplicate key for id (plus a typo).

Comment: I would, but it's not an answer. You should post your own solution as an answer, and accept that when you can.

Comment: Okay, though for me it's a valid solution since I specified `can you at least point me in some direction to keep testing it?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the user andrewsi I could solve my problem.

Basically, I had no idea where to look for mistakes, so I run this code `var_dump($STH->ErrorInfo());` to find out what was the problem and then fix it. My resulting code was:

```
//Simple script that connects to mysql and database.
$db = new PDO ("mysql:host=".Configuration::get('MysqlServername').";dbname=".Configuration::get('MysqlDatabase').";charset=UTF-8",
          Configuration::get('MysqlUsername'),
          Configuration::get('MysqlPassword')) or die ("Error connecting");

// To test why it doesn't work
$STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO htranslations (keyword, en, page, last) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())");
$STH->execute(array("New_test","New test",$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
var_dump($STH->ErrorInfo());
```

It returned a duplicate key, and that's when I realized that the code that worked (once) with old mysql_* didn't work here only because of a mistake in the database.

But I learned how to check out errors in the PDO way (well, still need the try/catch block) and hope that someone coming to this question with a similar error will solve it with this answer.